# Web application with NAT for outbound requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-vpc

I am attempting to set up a AWS VPC for the following use case:

- The web application must be able to scale as needed on a private subnet.
- The consumers of the web application will need to whitelist the IP addresses of the application as part of an initial setup process.
- The web application must be able to scale on demand without requiring customers to authorize additional public IPs.

I was able to create the VPC using the following guide:

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2781451301784570

I have confirmed that outbound requests originating from machines on the private subnets have the IP addresses NAT'd as expected. Though not necessarily relevant to the question, I have also confirmed that the NAT instances fail over properly to each other as needed (with a few updates to the scripts provided). Basically, everything is working as expected here.

The issue is connecting to a web client on the private subnets. I tried a few different options here, including assigning Elastic IPs and an ELB to the instance yielded the same result. Inbound traffic to the instances is received, but the responses from the instances is being routed through the NAT instances.

This is an example route table for the private subnets:

```
Destination Target Status Propagated
10.0.0.0/16 local Active No
0.0.0.0/0 eni-0e42d978 / i-1c0d43f7 Active No
```

This is an example route table for the public subnets:

```
Destination Target Status Propagated 
10.0.0.0/16 local Active No 
0.0.0.0/0 igw-e5429280 Active No
```

This is an example of the IP tables config on the NAT instances:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Fri Oct  3 19:08:18 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:84]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct  3 19:08:18 2014
```

For requests originating from the private subnet this is perfectly fine, its exactly as we expect. For requests originating from the public internet this ends up with responses being routed from an IP address the client does not expected, mangling any attempted HTTP connections.

Is there a way to modify the existing setup in the example above to allow inbound HTTP requests to the instances so that the responses are routed properly through the ELB?

Comment: Asymmetric routing should not be the case in the VPC scenario you've described. the ELBs that receive inbound requests should be in public subnets and the instances in private subnets. The instances will receive requests from an address in the public subnet that the ELB is placed in and will reply to that address. Only new connections that are initiated from the instance to outside the VPC will traverse the NAT.

Can you update your answer with `tcpdump` output for a request/response?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found out afterwards that the ELB was placed into in the private subnets which was causing the routing issue. After recreating a new ELB in the public subnets everything routed as expected.